# Codingbat make_bricks timed out with while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is:
We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks.

My code is:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if small + 5*big < goal:
    return False
  elif small + 5*big == goal:
    return True
  else:
    while small > 0:
      small -= 1
      goal -= 1
      if goal % 5 == 0 and big >= goal/5:
        return True
    return False
```

In my IDLE this works well, but codingbat resulted in TimedOut. Is it happenning because for big numbers `while` loop is too slow? I am using python 3.2.5.

EDIT:

I tried another code:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if small ==0:
    if goal % 5 == 0 and goal / 5 <= big:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  elif small + 5*big < goal:
    return False
  elif small + 5*big == goal:
    return True
  else:
    while small > 0:
      small -= 1
      goal -= 1
      if goal % 5 == 0 and big >= goal/5:
        return True
    return False
```

But with same issue.

Comment: What values of `small` result in a time out?

Comment: Timed out is in every column, but I read somewhere that when one result is timed out then all will result in timed out. But I see your question is deeper, you pointed it out. The problem may be when small == 0. Ill try.

Comment: Didnt work, same problem

Comment: What are big numbers ? because It doesn't seems to crash for me

Comment: biggest is make_bricks(1000000, 1000, 1000100)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I know why it doesn't work. Your code would work. But if there is a `loop` with about ~229500 (I tried to find the limit value on codebat, but sometime it timeout at this value, sometimes it doesn't. But the value is arround 230k) And as you said : One time out, and every value becomes time out. So to sum up, your code is working, but for the `make_bricks(1000000, 1000, 1000100) → True` test, there is a too big loop, and Codebat crashes.

So if you want to make it work on Codebat, you have to get rid of the `while` statement :

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    if small>=5 :
        if (goal - (big + (small // 5 - 1)) * 5) <= (small % 5 + 5):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else :
        if (goal - big * 5) % 5 <= (small % 5) : 
            return True
        else :
            return False
```

`small//5` return the `whole division`.
I think this is enought. (this should be the alst edit sorry)

Comment: Well thx, but my goal is not just solve it, but find a mistake as well. Can you see any problem in my code?

Comment: @Bobesh Your code is supposed to work. the logic work, there is no typo. Might be an issue with codebat that doesn't like while statement that does more than a few iteration (not to have infinite loop overloading them maybe). But I really beleive that what you did it right

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think CodingBat doesn't support `+=`, `-=`, etc. So if you change the lines containing that, you should not get a Timed Out. For example, `small -= 1` would become `small = small - 1`. I tested it and it worked on my end, in CodingBat.

Answer (score 0):

Just categorise the if statements according to whether the big bricks are cumulatively bigger or smaller than the goal.

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if (5*big) >= goal:
    return (goal%5) <= small
  if (5*big) < goal:
    return (goal - 5*(big)) <= small
```