# Why code is not working in CodingBat Make_Brick Problem but is working in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to answer the makeBricks `codingbat` [problem link](https://codingbat.com/prob/p118406).

I couldn't figure out any alternative, but came up with the following brute-force algorithm to solve the problem. I attempt every possible calculation to equal the goal.

I am able to get the code to run in `Jupyter notebook` (`anaconda python3`, but not in the `codingbat` website, which gives a `timed out` error. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
 def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

            # make a list of all the big and small bricks
            small_list=[]
            for i in range(small):
                small_list.append(1)
            #print(small_list)

            big_list=[]
            for i in range(big):
                big_list.append(5)

            #print(big_list)
            #print(goal)   

            target = goal

    # first see if the difference between the goal and a big brick is ==0,  
    # if not, start removing one small brick at a time to get to goal. if not reached
    # then take off another big brick and check again, then go and take off one
    # by one the small bricks and so on, if by the end you dont reach ==0 it means it is False.   


            for i in range(len(big_list)):
                target =target - big_list[i]
                #print(f'i is {i}, target is {target}')
                if target ==0:
                    return True
                for k in range(len(small_list)):
                        target=target-small_list[k]
                        #print(f'k is {k}, target is {target}')
                        if target ==0:
                            return True
                else:
                    target= goal-big_list[i]
                #print(f'target is {target}')

            #print(target)
            #print("done")
            if target !=0:
                return False
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found my answer on another person's questions here [Codingbat make_bricks timed out with while loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567853/codingbat-make-bricks-timed-out-with-while-loop-in-python?rq=1)

Basically, the brute-force method crashes the website for one or both of the following tests:

make_bricks(1000000, 1000, 1000100) → 
make_bricks(2, 1000000, 100003) →

They are just too big, and codingbat gives a "Timed-Out" error for all the problems.

Jupyter notebook keeps crunching but i ran out of patience to see if it succeeded :-)